# Calling browser.get more than once in a test throws btstrpd error in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I've just upgraded our project from Angular 1.2.25 to 1.3.6 and everything seems to have gone smoothly except our Protractor tests. This occurs in Protractor 1.3.1 and Protractor 1.5.0.

Calling `browser.get` more than once in a test raises this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/btstrpd.

We are bootstrapping our application using `data-ng-app`.

Passing "about:blank" to `browser.driver.get` between each call to `browser.get` fixes this. This seems like an confusing solution though.

Does anyone know what we might have done wrong to cause this issue or any insight towards a cleaner solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Which `protractor` version are you using? Also, when you call `browser.get` - all of the pages you open are angular-based?

Comment: You might also find [this thread](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/66) helpful.

Comment: @alecxe yes all the pages that we open are angular based. i'll read that thread now thanks!

Comment: may be important, what protractor version are you on?

Comment: @alecxe we were using 1.3.1 but i updated to 1.5.0 to see if that fixed the issue and this same error occurs in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `browser.get()` is used for initializing the browser with angular, and you're trying to do this more than once. Consider something more oriented around changing the location in an existing browser session like `browser.location()`?

Note: I have never used protractor and suck at tests.